# How to restructure/group this dataframe? (Multi-indexing?)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multi-index

I'm working with some flights data which I want to clean up since I want to be able to export it as a nice excel file. Below an example of this dataframe I have now can be seen, as well as an example of how I want it to look like. I've been trying all morning to get the desired result using group by and setting multiple indices, but I just cannot seem to get it right and might be needing a whole other approach that I'm unfamiliar with.

What I 'simply' want is that all Airports only occur once, having every unique date and amount of passengers once for every airport, alongside with the different crew members for every airport (which are always the same per airport, no matter the date).

Example of current dataframe:

| Index | Airport | Date | Crew | Passengers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BCN | 01-01-2022 | John | 312 |
| 2 | BCN | 01-01-2022 | Emily | 312 |
| 3 | BCN | 01-01-2022 | Luis | 312 |
| 4 | BCN | 01-01-2022 | Melissa | 312 |
| 5 | BCN | 01-01-2022 | Harry | 312 |
| 6 | BCN | 03-01-2022 | John | 140 |
| 7 | BCN | 03-01-2022 | Emily | 140 |
| 8 | BCN | 03-01-2022 | Luis | 140 |
| 9 | BCN | 03-01-2022 | Melissa | 140 |
| 10 | BCN | 03-01-2022 | Harry | 140 |
| 11 | LAX | 05-01-2022 | Fatima | 287 |
| 12 | LAX | 05-01-2022 | Chris | 287 |
| 13 | LAX | 05-01-2022 | David | 287 |

Example of desired dataframe:

| Index | Airport | Date | Passengers | Crew |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BCN | 01-01-2022 | 312 | John |
| 2 | - | 03-01-2022 | 140 | Emily |
| 3 | - | - | - | Luis |
| 4 | - | - | - | Melissa |
| 5 | - | - | - | Harry |
| 6 | LAX | 05-01-2022 | 287 | Fatima |
| 7 | - | - | - | Chris |
| 8 | - | - | - | David |

If anyone could help me with this issue it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the goal for display purposes or for further analysis

Comment: @Umar.H For now it's mainly for display purposes, as the current dataframe is quite unclear. Further analysis might be needed in the future, but I suppose that could always be done beforehand.

Comment: maybe something like `df.groupby(['Airport','Date', 'Crew'])['Passengers'].min()`

Comment: @Umar.H Unfortunately this doesn't work. Every single date will still have the crew members attached to it. So for the BCN example it would indeed show both dates once, but both of those dates still have all the crew members, while I want to have the crew members once for all dates (or once per Airport). This is the main problem I've been struggling with myself, as you need 5 rows to correspond with 2 rows.